# SCSS - hover on multiple element?

Tags: sass, hover

Hello ! My first post with my first problem... ! :D

I can't understand why my two elements are not affected by the hover.. Only the img is activated.

**My code Html**

```
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: `/live/${loginName}`,
      }}
    >

      <img
        src={image}
        alt={`stream ${gameName} in progress`}
        className="channelStream__img"
      />

    </Link>

    <span className="channelStream__viewers">{`${changeTypeNumberOfViewers(viewer)} spectateurs`}</span>

    <span className="channelStream__live">{type}</span>

  </header>
```

**My scss**

```
.channelStream {

&__img {

    &:hover {

    transform: translate(.4rem, -.4rem); 
  
      ~ .channelStream__live, ~ .channelStream__viewers {

        color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right about of closing brackets? I see 4 opening and 3 closing.
Additionally, it might be more stable to write the rule like `&__img:hover {}`
Also confirm that that numbers are the correct format.

Comment: Yes, the closing brackets are ok. i have tested many formats but nothing changes...
this hover works only on my img.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I find soluce for this problem !
I just changed of position the class, I think the problem comes from my double closing brackets..

my new code :

```
<header className="channelStream__header">
        <div className="backgroundImg" />
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `/live/${loginName}`,
          }}
          className="channelStream__link"
        >
          <img
            src={image}
            alt={`stream ${gameName} in progress`}
            className="channelStream__img"
          />
        </Link>
        <span className="channelStream__viewers">{`${changeTypeNumberOfViewers(viewer)} spectateurs`}</span>
        <span className="channelStream__live">{type}</span>
      </header>
```

and my css

```
&__link:hover {
    .channelStream__img, ~.channelStream__live, ~.channelStream__viewers {
    transform: translate(.4rem, -.4rem);      
    }
```